# Time condition in python

Tags: python

I have a python script monitor.py that analyzes text log. The log get generated by 'logging' module inside each python script from Scheduled Job and all results get logged to e.g. C:\log.txt file. I scheduled to run monitor.py script every hour. I don't want this c:\log.txt get growing and accumulate hence I think it would be a good idea to delete it sometime after midnight. Note: I don't have other scheduled jobs at night hence it will not have impact.
I want to check the current time, if the time is between 12:00 AM and 1:00 AM i.e. between midnight and 1 AM I will delete C:\log.txt and immidiately generate a new c:\log.txt file. I noticed that Scheduled Job on windows starts not exactly time it was scheduled but a few seconds before hence my prototype would be:
1. check if current time is between 23:59 PM and 1:00 AM
2. in case 1. is 'true' -> delete c:\log.txt and create a new c:\log.txt
My only problem is that I don't know how could create condition like:
 1:00 AM   < current time > 23:59 PM
Could someone help me on it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want this c:\log.txt get growing

You can use https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler or https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler to limit a logfile size.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I'm looking for another solution i.e. I want to delete file base on condition. Condition is time interval